# -moz-list-bullet Browser support?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Do the webkit, opera or internet explorer browsers have similiar property to `-moz-list-bullet`? I tried to search the browser support for this feature on google but could not find any information.

Comment: Are you aware that when searching with google on a word starting with a -, google returns results NOT containing that word? Anyway, Mozilla says that this is just a temporary measure until the CSS3 specs for ::marker become fixed, so it may be best to not use it for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `list-style-type: none;` and using the `::before` pseudo-element will work very similarly to `-moz-list-bullet` in all browsers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rurbN/

CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
    color: red;
    content: '\2605';
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This unfortunately does not work the same when text breaks into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

It is not listed anywhere in the browser style sheet property references:

- [Webcore html.css](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)
- [Presto specs](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/css/properties/)
- [Mozilla html.css](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)
- resource://gre-resources/html.css (Firefox browser internal style sheet)
- [MSDN: Generated and Replaced Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772051)